# Quarkus and Vaadin v24.x.x upgrade

Tags: vaadin, quarkus, vaadin24

When upgrading quarkus and vaadin version from v23.x.x to vaadin version 24.x.x I am getting an error:

```
cannot access jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper
```

Does some one knows how to fix this?

Quarkus version 2.16.5.Final

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vaadin 24 requires Jakarta EE 10. That will be Quarkus 3

From before the final release:

> The Java enterprise application ecosystem at large is making
> a backward-incompatible leap from the `javax.*` namespace into `jakarta.*`.
> To use next-generation application frameworks like Spring Boot 3 or **Jakarta
> EE 10 compatible application servers**, you'll need to use the
> soon-to-be-released Vaadin 24
>
> ---
>
> source: https://vaadin.com/blog/jakarta-ee-is-becoming-mainstream-get-ready-for-spring-boot-3-and-vaadin-24